# image doesn't show up in production server ( blue question mark )

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I have a chunk of code that is used to take pictures and resize them in small and medium formats. after this is done it gives back the photo in the desired format.

In the test server on my mac it works like a charm but on my production server ( a shared hosting ) it doesn't work as expected and it shows me blue question marks. If I go to the absolute map and url directly it shows me the photos. but using the controller route it shows me the question mark. I think the reason might be that I don't have imagine or imagick on the server installed.. altho if that was the reason it wouldn't resize the photo's as well would it? ( but it does )

i'd be really happy if someone could help me out here reviewing my code to see the mistake/error :) im new to silex/symfony so don't be too harsh on me!

The piece of code is

```
    $app->get('/img/{name}/{size}', function($name, $size, Request $request) use ($app) {
    $prefix = $app['upload_folder'].'/';
    $full_name = $prefix . $name;

    $thumb_name = '';
    $thumb_width = 320;
    $thumb_height = 240;

    if ( !file_exists( $full_name ) )
    {
        throw new \Exception( 'File not found' );
    }

    switch ( $size )
    {
        default:
        case 'small':
            $thumb_name = $prefix . 'small_' . $name;
            $thumb_width = 320;
            $thumb_height = 240;
            break;

        case 'medium':
            $thumb_name = $prefix . 'medium_' . $name;
            $thumb_width = 1024;
            $thumb_height = 768;
            break;
    }

    $out = null;

    if ( 'original' == $size )
    {
        $out = new BinaryFileResponse($full_name);
    }
    else
    {
        if ( !file_exists( $thumb_name ) )
        {
            $app['imagine']->open($full_name)
                ->thumbnail(
                    new Imagine\Image\Box($thumb_width,$thumb_height),
                    Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET)
                ->save($thumb_name);
        }

        $out = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse($thumb_name);
    }

    return $out;
})
->value('size', 'small');
```

Comment: Did you disable browser caching? I had this issue before, but with a forum software; turned out yo be a combination of the browser cache, and the hosts' varnish cache. May be a good idea to consult with your host about this issue, since it obviously is an issue with the hosts' configuration.

Comment: @zyboxinternational where do I disable/enable that? I don't think so since testing it locally same time and same picture it works like a charm just when I try to use this controller to get the desired photo it doesn't work.. :o

Comment: Usually a Ctrl+Shift+F5 disables caching for a specific page. Since it's shared hosting, I'm assuming you're at least partially using a web browser to access it.

Comment: I don't think its cache related to be honest.. otherwise it wouldn't work on my local machine as well would it?

Comment: rm -rf app/cache/*;app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug;app/console assets:install;app/console assetic:dump;app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug

Comment: @johnSmith ehh? sorry what is this for?